# how i can get the updated position before apply rotation in javafx?

Tags: rotation, javafx-2, transformation

i got this class but when i print the line.endXProperty().get() when the rotatios is apply the property doesn't change the value,

¿how can i get the updated value after transform?

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        root = new Group();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        line = new Line();
        line.setStrokeWidth(5.0);
        line.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        line.setStartX(10.0f);
        line.setStartY(80.0f);
        line.setEndX(10.0f);
        line.setEndY(10.0f);
        System.out.println("line.getEndX()="+line.endXProperty().get());
        rotate = new Rotate(90, 10.0f, 80.0f);
        line.getTransforms().add(rotate);

        System.out.println("line.getEndX()="+line.endXProperty().get());

        root.getChildren().add(line);

        stage.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
Point2D transformedEnd = line.localToScene(line.getEndX(), line.getEndY());
```